# String interpolation in Ruby doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, string

Recently I shifted to Ruby 2.0.0 from Ruby 1.9.3.

In 1.9.3 we were used to perform string interpolation using: `'http://#{get_host_name}.com`, but since moving to 2.0.0, it seems to be not working.

Can anyone tell me if the syntax changed?  How can I perform string interpolation in Ruby 2.0.0?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regardless of which version of Ruby you're using, string interpolation doesn't happen in single-quoted strings.  Use double-quoted strings or `%Q`-style strings.